# Geometry- power center or something?

Tags: geometry

Let $A,B$ belong to $(O)$ and $AB$ doesn't through $O$. $M$ is apoint in the linesegment $AB$ such that $MA>MB$. Let $\Delta$ is a line through $M$ and perpendicular to $OM$ and call $P,Q$ be the intersections of $(O)$ and $\Delta$. Let $(I)$ be the circle with diameter $AM$ and this circle intersects $(O)$ at $K$ where $K\ne A$. Let $D$ be the intersection of $PQ$ and $(I)$ such that $D\ne M$. $S$ is the intersections of $PQ$ and $AK$, $F$ is inter intersections of $SB$ and $(O)$ and $H$ is orthocenter of $\triangle APQ$. Prove that $M,H,K$ are colinear and $HF$ always through the fix point when $M$ move on linesegment $AB$.[image]

I have tried to prove $PKML$ is cocyclic and see that is $S$ is power-center of three cycle $(O),(I)$ and the cycle through $D,F,M,B$. Somebody can give me some hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend $AO$ to meet the circumcircle of $\triangle APQ$ at point $C$. $K$ is intersection point of  $CM$ with the circle.

$O$ is the circumcentre of $\triangle APQ$ and $OM\perp PQ$. Hence if $H$ is the orthocentre of $\triangle APQ$, $AH=2OM$. Extend $MK$ and $AD$ to meet at some point $R$. Observe that $AR=2OM$ and since $R$ lies on the perpendicular from $A$ on $PQ$,  $R$ is $H$, the orthocentre of $\triangle APQ$. Thus,  points $H$, $M$ and $K$ are collinear.

Now,  observe that,  in $\triangle HAM$, $MD\perp HA$ and $AK\perp HM$ and hence $S$, the intersection of those two perpendiculars, is the orthocentre of $\triangle HAM$.

Now, in quadrilateral $HFSK$, $\angle KFS=\angle KFB=\angle KAB=\angle KAM=\angle MHS=\angle KHS$ and thereafter it is cyclic. Therefore, $\angle HFB=90^{\circ}$ and hence $HF$ passes through the intersection of $BO$ with the circumcircle of $\triangle APQ$, a fixed point.

Comment: amazing solution! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Dat Tran You're welcome. This was a nice problem.